# How can simply this function

Tags: python, function, dictionary

Can I simply this function:

```
def fun1(param, value, send):
    if send == True:
        fun2(**{param:value})
    else:
        fun2()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the `if...else` **inside** the function argument:

```
def fun1(param, value, send):
    return fun2(**({param:value} if send else {}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to write this function is as follows:

```
def fun1(param, value, send):
    fun2(**{param:value}) if send == True else fun2()
```

The syntax is:

```
a if condition_meets else b
```